# Computing PageRank using formula by iterating through adjacency matrix

Tags: python, r, matrix, seo, pagerank

I have created an adjacency matrix in excel spreadsheet, and now I need to calculate the page rank of each page by using teleportation constant T=0.15 and using the following formula:

```
PR(W)=T/N+(1-T)(PR(W1)/O(W1)+PR(W2)/O(W2)+...PR(Wn)/O(WN))
```

I believe the pseudo-code to perform this action should be something like this:

```
x=formula
for i in range(len(matrix):
 if i=1, then i==x
   else
    return 0
print(i?)
```

I know it is far from being perfect, and I am still trying to work this through.

I also suppose that I need firstly declare create a separate program code for the formula itself and declare its variables.

Would this be a a satisfying solution to implement this idea with Python or R? Or there is a better method of calculating page rank?

I came across various possible solution in the web, but they weren't very helpful in relation with my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If your data isn't especially big, and I assume it isn't, since it's in an excel spreadsheet, you can simply compute the first eigenvector of a prepared matrix `A`. Let your adjacency matrix be named `M`. The code in R is as follows:

```
n = ncol(M)
B = matrix(1/n, n, n) # the teleportation matrix
A = 0.85 * M + 0.15 * B
ranks = eigen(A)$vectors[1] # your PageRanks
```

If your matrix is bigger, then you can use for example function `page_rank` from package `igraph`

Comment: This looks nice, thank you very much!

Although, I have some error messages:

 n = ncol(m)
 B = matrix(1/n, n, n) # the teleportation matrix
> A = 0.85*m+0.15*B
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
 ranks = eigen(A)$vectors[1] # your PageRanks
Error in eigen(A) : non-square matrix in 'eigen'

I don't have much experience with R, so I am struggling to find an answer to this particular case.

The matrix is 500x500 whit 1 and 0.

Comment: please ignore my last comment, that was my own mistake regarding data

now I have this output:
` ranks = eigen(A)$vectors[500] # your PageRanks
> n = ncol(R)
> B = matrix(1/n, n, n) # the teleportation matrix
> A = 0.85 * R + 0.15 * B
> ranks = eigen(A)$vectors[500] # your PageRanks
> print(ranks)
[1] -0.0002985959+0i`

that actually works, but I need a PageRanks for each page, ideally it would look like:

`Iteration <iteration number>
<URL1><PageRank1>
... `

or as a table

As I understand, $vectors[1] is an array which stores the general result and is represented in ranks